Autodesk Forge - Get grouped elements by Classification
has anyone ever dealt with extracting IFCCLASSIFICATION from a model in Autodesk Forge Viewer?
I'm looking to group all elements based on this IFCCLASSIFICATION parameter found within the structure of an IFC file. Can anyone help me with that, please?
This is how IFCCLASSIFICATION looks in the structure of an IFC model:
enter image description here
Here is the link to buildingsmart.org: https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/DEV/IFC4_2/FINAL/HTML/schema/ifcexternalreferenceresource/lexical/ifcclassification.htm.
This is how sorting by classification looks in another viewer:
enter image description here

When using the v3 translation (that's default for e.g. Autodesk Viewer shown in the below image) then the SVF should contain the IFCCLASSIFICATION info if it was available in the original file

IFC translation options:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/jobs/job-POST/#body-structure

Based on the property value you should be able to find the elements that have the same - and e.g. select them in the Viewer:
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/property-based-selection-isolation

Alright, thank you for the response, this solution works well.
